# CSV for DataGridView with serialization/deserialization

Tags: .net, asp.net, dataadapter

I want to create a UI for CSV parsing/editing/update via aspx page, and I'm currently investigating DataGridView option. It seems there are ready to use "Update", "Edit" functions that should, more or less, create a ready to use interface. Although they don't seem to work with CSV so far (missing edit/update commands).

But since I haven't been programming in .NET for couple of years, I just can't find what's the best way to tackle the problem in short time-frame.

Seems that the CSV reader has to be based around SQL adapter with connection string to "Microsoft Text Provider", but that requires SQL update/delete statements, doesn't it? And also, different separators are causing problems ",;\t".

Should I just skip all this .NET specific way of dealing with data, and just write my own parser with simple table?

Is there a good cheat-sheet where I can quickly gaze over differences between datagrids and dataadapters to understand which one I should choose for the task, and pros/cons for each of them.

I'm really not looking forward towards 10 days of documentation study as I'm not planning to use .NET in future much, but somehow I just can't find what I'm looking for in docs/articles, and I don't want to re-implement all the functionality that's widely available from scratch.

Can anyone give me a hint where to look for answers that doesn't involve hours of wasted time on semi-relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing stuff here. `DataGridView` is just a presentation of data. CSV is format of data. So you just need to read CSV file into a bindable structure and bind to the grid. The grid itself provides UI for editing, updating etc, but it's up to you to serialize the data that is the grid bound to back to CSV.

Although you can use MS Text Provider, it requires the provider to be installed on the machine, so you'll depend on it. I'd suggest you to either create your own parser (it's quite an easy format), or use some open-source library, e.g. http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: Yea, I'm still trying to understand all the flow. So far it seems chain is somewhat like: (DataGrid/ListView/FormView/...)<->(DataAdapter/SqlDataAdapter/DataSet/?DataTable?) And the combinations seem endless...

Comment: Well, it's up to you what you use. You don't need anything of that, it's about your scenario. If you only need to parse CSV's from file and write back to that file, you don't need DataAdapters or DataSets at all, these are meant for work with database systems. Seems it won't be possible to work on something without studying some documents at all.

Comment: I'm not against studying documents, but I want to find a compact document. Interfaces/DataFlow/Objects. MSDN only covers classes it seems, not their relationships and purposes.

Comment: MSDN also has overviews, not only class references. But there are plenty of tutorials about asp.net and databinding on the web. For example, see how easy it can be if you don't need database access: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial94_How-to-bind-a-DataGrid-to-an-array.html or http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/BindArrayDL.aspx
That could be your case, the easiest CSV memory representation (if you don't know the column structure) could be a list of arrays.

Comment: Never knew it's possible to use simple arrays as datasource. I guess this is the right direction.